# Nginx use placeholder in location (nginx.conf)

Tags: ssl, nginx, proxy, nginx-location

I want to use nginx as a revers ssl proxy.

I have a reset service with multiple apis and I want to have a place holder in the location configuration and use it in the proxy_pass

```
location /myapp/(\s+)/(\s+) {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:9000/$1/$2;

  }
```

Any idea how do I do it ?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/586614/211028

Comment: Thank you! It was very helpful.